# Using XML elements

Tags: c#, winforms

I have working code that I'd simply like to reference parts of multiple times in other area's of my program, however my problem seems to be with anonymous types (var)

here's a section of my program that loads my XML file

```
string path = "Data//handling4.meta";
            var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var items = doc.Descendants("HandlingData").Elements("Item");
            var query = from x in items

                        select new
                        {
                            HandlingName = (string)x.Element("handlingName"),
                            HandlingType = (string)x.Element("HandlingType"),
                            Mass = (decimal?)x.Element("fMass").Attribute("value"),
                            InitialDragCoeff = (decimal?)x.Element("fInitialDragCoeff").Attribute("value"),
                            PercentSubmerged = (decimal?)x.Element("fPercentSubmerged").Attribute("value"),
                            DriveBiasFront = (decimal?)x.Element("fDriveBiasFront").Attribute("value")
                        };
```

This code works great, I can also use a foreach loop like this to reference items

```
 foreach(var HandlingName in query)
        {
            string Names = HandlingName.HandlingName;
        }
```

So my question is,  **how to reference that to another place in the program?** for e.g.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add( Names);
        }
```

The above code throws the error 'Names does not exist in the current context'

I need for my comboBox to display each handling name, but it fails because anonymous types cannot be referenced. Am I doing something wrong, or am I just not using the incorrect method? Thanks

Edit: Also to mention that the XML is needing to be referenced in multiple parts of the program, button click even shows the values in a DataGridView for example. If I could make a class to load the XML, then each element in different area's of the program that'd be ideal, rather than loading the hefty block of code each time

Comment: Far from clear, but the obvious answer is to make Names a property or private member of the class this lot is defined in, instead of using a locally defined variable.

Comment: Sorry, I should of also mentioned that I'm new to programming, if you could produce an answer to show what you're saying I'd really appreciate it

Comment: A compiler error is not a 'throw'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the XML is needing to be referenced in multiple parts of the program,

But all your variables are local. You need to store something in a Form fiead or property.

```
// outside any method:
private List<string> names = new List<string>();

void myLoadMethod()
{
    ...
    foreach(var HandlingName in query)
    {
        //string Names = HandlingName.HandlingName;
        Names.Add(HandlingName.HandlingName);
    }  
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add( Names);
}
```

Comment: That solution shows 'Collection' rather than the handlingNames inside comboBox after clicking the button

Comment: Yeah, right. You need `Items.AddRange(Names)` or write a loop. Note that your question doesn't even tell me if it's WinForms or ASP.NET.

Comment: @DannyNichols:  Re your Edit, it should _not_ be static or public... those are easy cop-outs you'll come to regret. Learn proper state and instance management.

Comment: "use the items" is a different story. Yielding them as anonymous-type objects prevents that. Write a proper `HandlingData` class first. And do avoid `static`, you really don't need/want it here.